# Is this a Design issue or Eclipse's issue or Java's loophole?

Tags: java, eclipse, class-design

Let us have the following classes defined in eclipse's work space:

```
public abstract class A {
   public void foo() {
      System.out.println("Hi.. this is foo()");
   }
}

public interface I {
   void foo();
}

public class B extends A implements I {
   public void bark() {
      System.out.println("Hi.. this is bark()");
   }
}

public class C {
   public void woo() {
      I i = new B();
      i.foo();
   }
}
```

Now the problem is eclipse doesn't show any references for A.foo() on searching through

- References -> Project or
- References - Hierarchy

I see this a design issue. What do you think?

Comment: This is certainly connected with how eclipse find references. It doesn't have to do anything with Java itself...

Comment: I don't know about the Eclipse side, but it feels odd to me that A isn't declared as implementing I.

Comment: Technically, this may be legal. Practically, as Matthew said, this just feels dirty, could be why Eclipse's guys never implemented smthn like this...

Comment: Yes even I agree with Matthew & TC1.. this just feels dirty.. Is it better to have an abstract class A implements I

Answer (score 0):

Sounds perfectly reasonable to me as in your provided code `A` does *not* implement `I`, only `B` does. Event though in declaration of `B` code reads out `extends A implements I` it does not mean `A` would retrospectively be implementing interface `I` - it says "B extends A and also implements I".

Comment: I think we should avoid designing like this.. That is we should avoid writing concrete method at an independent abstract class..

Comment: Is it better to have an abstract class A implements I

Comment: In class B, the implementation of interface I comes from class A. In other words, A.foo must fulfil the contract demanded by I, and logically, it must be reasonable to say that A implements I.

Comment: Code is `public abstract class A`, not `public abstract class A implements I`, therefore A does _not_ implement I

Comment: In the existing code, A is not marked as implementing I - sure. I was trying to say that it would be more logical to mark A as implementing I.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Eclipse:

```
A a = new A() { };
a.foo(); // <-- A.foo() found this reference by Eclipse in "References -> Project"
```

Comment: Yes, thats true. 
<pre><code>
    public class C {
      public void woo() {
        I i = new B();
        i.foo();//references cannot be found from A.foo() since A has not implemented I
        B b = new B();
        b.foo();//references can be found from A.foo()
        A a = new B();
        a.foo();//references can be found from A.foo()
      }
    }</pre></code>